# GDScript: Rotation function doesn't work properly

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to program a "Pong"-like game in Godot 3.5.
In contrast to the classic Pong game, i want to establish the possibility to slightly rotate the Pong-bars to get more variety.
After the player sets some rotation to the Pong bar, I want to correct it slowly to the starting point with an rotation of 0.
Somehow, my correction-function does only work on negative rotation_degrees ("left"). If there are positive rotation_degrees ("right"), no correction applies.

My code looks like this. I was already looking for bugs with the print-method.
The function correction is setting the rotation_direction to -0.2 as it should, but somehow the rotation_direction in the line above (see my bug comment) seems to keep the value 0.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var rotation_direction = 0
var max_rotation = 10

func _physics_process(delta):

    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        rotation_direction = 0.5
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        rotation_direction = -0.5
    

    rotation_degrees += rotation_direction ##possible bug?
    rotation_degrees = clamp(rotation_degrees, -max_rotation, max_rotation)
    correction()

func correction():
    if rotation_degrees > 0:
        rotation_direction = -0.2
    if rotation_degrees < 0.0:
        rotation_direction = 0.2
    else:
        rotation_direction = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Wrapping rotation

*This is not the issue at hand. As the issue I address here would only happen on large rotations. Yet, it will help other people with similar problems. And it will dispel your suspicions on the bug.*

General advice is to wrap your angles, like this:

```
wrapf(angle, -PI, PI)
```

or for degrees:

```
wrapf(angle_degrees, -180, 180)
```

So you can let the angle accumulate, and when you need to check it, you wrap it, so you have them representing the rotation the short way around. *For example a three quarters turns becomes a negative quarter turn.*

Which is important if you are going to limit the rotation to a range:

```
rotation_degrees = clamp(wrapf(rotation_degrees, -180, 180), -max_rotation, max_rotation)
```

---

### The bug

In `correction`, `rotation_direction` will either be `0.2` or `0.0`:

```
func correction():
    if rotation_degrees > 0:
        rotation_direction = -0.2
    if rotation_degrees < 0.0:
        rotation_direction = 0.2
    else:
        rotation_direction = 0.0
```

Yes, you have this `if` statement:

```
    if rotation_degrees > 0:
        rotation_direction = -0.2
```

Yet, no matter what, the second if statement will run, and the execution flow will enter one of it branches:

```
    if rotation_degrees < 0.0:
        rotation_direction = 0.2
    else:
        rotation_direction = 0.0
```

Minimal change would be to use `elif`:

```
func correction():
    if rotation_degrees > 0:
        rotation_direction = -0.2
    elif rotation_degrees < 0.0:
        rotation_direction = 0.2
    else:
        rotation_direction = 0.0
```

However, I would encourage to use `sign` (`signf` in Godot 4):

```
func correction():
    rotation_direction = -sign(rotation_degrees) * 0.2
```

Here `sign` will return either `-1`, `0` or `1` representing the sign of `rotation_degrees`. We negate it to get the opposite sign. And once multiplied with `0.2` the possible values are `0.2`, `0.0`, and `-0.2`.

Yes, you might wrap the angle there too:

```
func correction():
    rotation_direction = -sign(wrapf(rotation_degrees, -180, 180)) * 0.2
```

And since that is just one line, you might consider doing it in `_physics_process` instead of having a separate `correction` method.